# Annotating return type as `None` for routes that just raise `HTTPException` is not valid

Tags: python, type-hinting, aiohttp, python-typing

### Context

In `aiohttp` there is a type definition for a functional route handler in the [`typedefs`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/v3.8.3/aiohttp/typedefs.py#L62) module.

```py
Handler = Callable[["Request"], Awaitable["StreamResponse"]]
```

As you can see, the type is fairly straightforward: A callable that takes a `Request` as its sole argument and returns a simple awaitable that eventually yields a `StreamResponse`.

Yet this doesn't account for the fact that some handlers may not return anything at all, while still being perfectly valid and usable in the context of `aiohttp`, namely when all they do is raise a subclass of `HTTPException`.

#### MRE

The simplest practical example I can think of is some `POST` route that processes the provided payload and simply tells the client `200 OK`:

```py
from aiohttp.web import Application, HTTPOk, Request, RouteTableDef, run_app

routes = RouteTableDef()

@routes.post("/foo")
async def foo(request: Request) -> None:
    # process payload in some way...
    raise HTTPOk()

app = Application()
app.add_routes(routes)
run_app(app, host="localhost")
```

This seems to be entirely in line with how the [HTTP exceptions](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_quickstart.html#exceptions) are meant to be used. And the annotations of that function are obviously correct. Yet `mypy` for example rightfully complains:

```
error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "Callable[[Request], Coroutine[Any, Any, None]]"; expected "Union[Type[AbstractView], Callable[[Request], Awaitable[StreamResponse]]]"  [arg-type]
```

If we ignore the class-based `AbstractView` option, this tells us what we would expect: That the function's return type is `None`, but it is expected to be `StreamResponse`.

It would obviously be wrong, if I annotate the function with a `Response` return type, because **it doesn't return anything**.

So I am in a bit of a pickle here.

#### Question(s)

Am I missing something obvious or is this an inconsistency in the `aiohttp` type definitions?

I this worth opening an issue over? Or is there an entirely different way I could/should write such a function?

And please don't tell me that I can *"just use `type: ignore`, bro"*.

Comment: And does `typing.NoReturn` work for you? It should be compatible and means exactly "does not return, but raises or is stuck forever". It also should be compatible with any return type of superclass, AFAIC. It is not in `typedefs` for this reason: `NoReturn | Something` union reduces to just `Something`. It is worth opening an issue, if there is no one, but for documentation: this should be explained in the docs.

Comment: @SUTerliakov Brilliant! While I was writing this question I actually realized that I never thought of how to annotate such a function that _actually doesn't return_ (not one that returns `None`). In the context of `aiohttp` this is still meaningful, but otherwise I never came across it. I must have totally missed `NoReturn` because of that. Thanks a lot. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it. I guess I would still argue that the `Handler` type definition is a bit misleading, but maybe that was their intent - that people use `NoReturn` in such cases.